# Creating an append-only table in Postgres using revoke on all roles and granting insert to all roles

Tags: postgresql, sql-revoke

I would like to create an enforced append only table in my postgres db.
After a bit of research, I realized that a solution that will answer my requirements will be to revoke ALL operations on that table from ALL roles and then run an insert priveleges to all these roles, like so:

```
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE ticket_trail FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT INSERT ON TABLE ticket_trail TO PUBLIC;
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I think that revoking it from PUBLIC does not revoke it from my admin user or other users that I have.

How can I revoke ALL from ALL roles and then GRANT INSERT to all these roles again?
Any better ways to achieve an enforced append only table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better add a `before update or delete` trigger with a trivial trigger function that returns `null`. This will work for all users regardless of their roles and privileges.

```sql
create function abort_tf() returns trigger language plpgsql as
$$
begin
  return null;
end;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER no_update_or_delete_t
BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON ticket_trail 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION abort_tf();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to revoke the privileges that were granted. If you want to revoke a privilege that was granted to `admin`, you have to revoke it from `admin` specifically. There is no wholesale command "revoke everything from everybody".

If you are using `psql`, you could use `\gexec`:

```
SELECT format(
          'REVOKE %s ON %s FROM %s',
          a.privilege_type,
          t.oid::regclass,
          a.grantee::regrole
       )
FROM pg_class AS t
   CROSS JOIN aclexplode(t.relacl) AS a(p)
WHERE oid = 'x'::regclass \gexec
```

Answer (score 0):

setup

```
begin;
create role test_user1 NOCREATEDB NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEROLE LOGIN;
create role test_user2 NOCREATEDB NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEROLE LOGIN;
create role test_user3 NOCREATEDB NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEROLE LOGIN;
grant create, USAGE on schema public to test_user1;
set session authorization  test_user1;
select current_role;
create table public.ticket_trail(a int);
grant select,delete, insert,update,trunCATE on  public.ticket_trail to test_user2,test_user3 ;
set session authorization  test_user2;
insert into public.ticket_trail values(1);
set session authorization  test_user3;
insert into public.ticket_trail values(1);
end;
```

revoke all the grantee privileges in **superuser** session.

```
DO $func$
DECLARE
    r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT DISTINCT
        grantee
    FROM
        information_schema.role_table_grants
    WHERE
        table_name = 'ticket_trail'
    EXCEPT
    SELECT
        rolname
    FROM
        pg_authid
    WHERE
        rolsuper LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE 'test r grantee: %', r.grantee;
            EXECUTE 'revoke all PRIVILEGES on table ticket_trail from  ' || quote_ident(r.grantee) || ' cascade';
            REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM test_user1 CASCADE;
        END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Now it's clean. Only the owner and superuser can grant privilege to other role. You may want using  `alter table public.ticket_trail owner to new_role`
change the table ownership.